# How to set xpm icon on an executable in linux

Tags: linux, icons

I downloaded eclipse for developing some java on my centos 5.9 linux machine.
After extracting the files that came zipped to a folder I noticed one of the contents was a file called icon.xpm.

I know xpm files can be set as icons for executables but how would one go about doing so?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to edit (or create) a `.desktop` file for the program and put it in either `~/.local/applications/` (for a single user) or `/usr/share/applications/` (shared across all accounts).

It would look something like this example `eclipse.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Eclipse
GenericName=Integrated Development Application
Comment=Eclipse
Exec=/usr/local/bin/eclipse
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development;IDE;
```

[Here](http://linuxcritic.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/anatomy-of-a-desktop-file/) is a decent source for starting with your own `.desktop` files.

You would obviously need to update the above to the locations of your executable and icon.

Answer (score 1):

I had no success using the Eclipse icon in Ubuntu 18.04 and gave up. I have finally converted it to a PNG file and it was working promptly without issues. There seems to be an issue with this special XPM file or XPMs in general.